# Is it 'safe' to use standard Jubilee clips(Hose Clamps) instead of OEM clips on carb>Head Insulator?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, carburetor, oem

I have many Jubilee clips(*Hose clamps* to you maybe) so it would peeve me to spend over £20 on [Carb Insulator Bands](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/HONDA-MAGNA-VF-1100-V65-V-65-500-700-750-XL-CARB-BOOT-CLAMP-INSULATOR-BAND-84-86-/263180919118?epid=1411805913&hash=item3d46ce214e:g:WAwAAOSwo4pYPMS6) if I don't really need them.

[The Carb Insulator Rubbers connect the carb to the Head inlet.](https://www.bike-parts-honda.com/pieces-honda-detail-5757-13KPC1S1-XL125V2-2002-E__0200-125+VARADERO.html#)
[image]
*(top of image) no.8 = Carb Insulator Rubbers  no.9, 21 = Insulator Bands*

To fit them on, I would need to cut two protruding knobs off the [Insulator Rubbers](https://www.cmsnl.com/xl125v-varadero-2001-1-germany_model6487/insulator-carb_16211kgb610/#.Wa7QCvmGPGg), which are only there to stop the OEM clip from sliding around, making access to the bolt difficult.

Is there anything stopping me from using Jubilee clips for this task? Maybe something to do with the temperature or the petrol(gasoline) or even oil affecting the clips?

I can't foresee any problems myself, but I thought I'd check with you guys before I commit.

### Jubilee Clip

[image: A Standard Jubilee Clip/Hose Clamp (Image)]

### OEM Clip

[image: OEM Carb Insulator Clips (Image)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it *wouldn't* be safe. Each performs the exact same function: to prevent leakage between the outer soft part and the inner hard part (whatever might leak through) ... (yah, that's a lot of words to just say "form a seal").

The main reason the OEM clips are used is they are *cheaper to produce* en mass. Even if you save $.02 per clamp by using the OEM ones over the jubilee, when you're talking a few hundred thousand clamps, you're talking thousands and thousands in savings to the manufacturer.

If you have any doubt why cars like Mercedes are more expensive, it's because they use things like superior hose clamps. Below is an example of a genuine OEM Mercedes-Benz hose clamp (or jubilee, if you prefer):

[image]

Go to pick apart yards which handles MB vehicles and get yourself some for cheap.

Comment: That ring seems familiar actually. Maybe I've seen one kicking around before. Thanks for the good advice. I would have thought OEM clips were more expensive to make, as they are more expensive to buy. Makes sense they'd pick the cheaper option though.

Answer (score 1):

They'll likely be fine, however just double check that everything is sealing properly, as quite often many of those OEM bands are slightly narrower compared to jubilee clips, and so they sit in the carbs insulator sleeves perfectly thus creating a proper seal.

Answer (score 1):

The two are functionally equivalent. Just be cognizant of the possibility of physical interference with other components when you use the generic clip in lieu of the OEM one.